# When is is correct to use 'to' after 'must' and how it affects the meaning?

Tags: modal-verbs, to-infinitive

I have seen some scenarios where we use 'to' after 'must'.

> All languages are must to learn.

This usage is correct while,

> You must to learn cooking.

This usage is wrong.

Why is it wrong in terms of meaning?

Comment: The syntax of your first example is invalid, because you need to include the article: *All languages are **a** must to learn.* But then there's a *semantic* problem, because it makes no sense to assert that it's necessary for a person to learn ***all*** languages. A valid example might be ***English is a must to learn***, or even ***English and Chinese are a must to learn nowadays***.

Comment: The relevant usage here is [**must**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/must) (noun) *Something that should not be overlooked or missed* (note - this sense is *extremely* uncommon as a plural).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - bandages, antibiotics, and good running shoes are probably musts when you are starting to learn lion taming. Being intentional and competitive are musts when buying a home right now, recognizing and taking action are musts when it comes to controlling challenging behaviors with our children.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I said [the plural usage is **uncommon**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+a+must%2Care+musts&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), and there's no doubt that ***are musts*** practically flatlines in Google NGrams compared to the singular ***is a must***.  I certainly don't claim there's anything "invalid" about the plural - but per my first comment, I would actually prefer the singular in my own example. I'm afraid ***English and Chinese are musts to learn nowadays*** seems like a bit of a mouthful to me (it's too much trouble to articulate /s/).

Answer (score 4):

*Must*, like all modals, takes the base form of the following verb, not a *to* infinitive. Always.

*Must* is also a noun, meaning "something that you must have". Your first sentence needs "a", and says "Languages are **a must** to learn", or to turn it round "To learn languages is a must". Even with this nominal use of *must*, the *to* is not governed by it, but is a different constituent of the sentence.

Comment: I just love it when  answers state things clearly. Yes, all modals must take the base form of the following verb.